# block all xmlrpc.php requests globally cpanel server

Tags: apache, cpanel, xml-rpc

I have Googled around a lot looking for a working example of blocking all xmlrpc.php requests on my cpanel server. I've tried CSF option which seems to work only if the requests come from the same ip (which they do not),  I've tried modsecurity option which everyone seems to think works, but it doesnt do anything, requests still come in and are processed for xmlrpc.php... Also tried apache config changes for "Files" with "deny" and all that, also does not work... requests are always still allowed and still processed....

does anyone out there have a working example of how to totally disable xmlrpc.php on all sites on a cpanel server with cloudlinux and cagefs?

Answer (score 1):

I use a pre-main global include (WHM -> Service Configuration -> Apache Configuration -> Pre-Main Include -> All Versions) to block xmlrpc server-wide:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
  RedirectMatch 301 /xmlrpc.php http://127.0.0.1/
</IfModule>
```